# File permissions on a Solaris system - using ACl or sticky bit?

Tags: solaris, acl, ufs

I have a problem on my Solaris file server, with UFS file system.

I have created a folder on my file server called "projects" intended for storing
all files connected with projects that we are currently working on, allowing for several people to collaborate using the same files.

What I would like to achieve is that files and folder dropped here automatically has the group set to proj, for example, and thus are accessible and editable for all members of the group proj.

As is is set up now the users have to run a script manually to change the group on all files and folders in the folder but I have several users that drop files from a windows environment with no possibility of doing this.

So my question is: is it possible to set up this using either ACL or using sticky bits or using any other brilliant solution, and how would I do this?

Comment: Might also have luck asking this one on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Is this folder served with NFS, SMB or something else?

Comment: @Richard: We're using SMB
@squillman: Ok, thank you, will remember that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Solaris, bit 02000 of the file mode determines whether a directory has BSD group ID semantics (when set) or System V semantics (when clear).  This is the 'set group ID' bit, and is set by 'chmod g+s ' (and cleared with g-s).  BSD semantics is that the group ID for a newly created file in that directory will be that of the directory, rather than the System V version, that of the creating process.

Comment: Perfect, setting g+s solved our problem, in combination with adding "force group = proj" to smb.conf.

Thank you!